# Enter key should save and close and escape key should close without save

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, keyboard-events

In VB.NET, Windows form details should save. If I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it should save and close and the escape key should close without save.

Currently it happens on the onclick event of a button of Save and Cancel, but I wish the keyboard events also work.

Any quick code to do that is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the AcceptButton and CancelButton properties on your form.